# I can't get any of the sticky footer tutorials I've read to work on my wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I must be missing something with the sticky footer tutorials I've been reading, because none of them make the slightest bit of difference to my wordpress site / theme.

At the moment, the content pushes my footer down, but it never sits at the bottom of the page unless there's something to push it there.

My css is:

```
body{ 
margin: 0; 
min-width: 100%;    
height: auto !important;
}

.header {
width: 75%;
max-width: 75%;
height: 40px;
padding-top: 32px;
padding-bottom:32px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  
}

.content {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
max-width:100%;
height: auto;
}

.footer {  
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1.5px; 
border-top-color: #e1e1e1;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 25px;
width: 75%;
max-width:75%;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is there a sure-shot way of achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean by "content pushing it down" ? Do you mean that the footer is always displayed until you scroll down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position of your footer to `absolute` with a `bottom:0;` and adjust it

```
html {
position:relative;
min-height:100%;
}

.content {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
max-width:100%;
height: auto;
padding-bottom:50px; //to avoid content overlaping the footer
}

.footer {  
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1.5px; 
border-top-color: #e1e1e1;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 25px;
width: 75%;
max-width:75%;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:12,5%; // Since the footer width is 75%
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this sort of works. The problem now is that since it's been positioned absolutely, it no longer gets pushed down when the content div is longer than the screen and you have to scroll down. I'm guessing there's no way to do this with it as position:relative ? You can see what I mean here, the content overlaps the footer. http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/macro/

Comment: set body position to relative !

Comment: Hi Younes, thanks for getting back to me – I've added the above css and it seems that setting the body to position:relative brings back the original problem of the footer jumping to the top instead of staying at the bottom when there's no content on the page.

Comment: Ok I think that I solved the problem. Try setting `html` tag position to relative and `min-height` to 100%. (As above)

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thanks for all your help, this is one that I've been trying to tackle for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

I usually accomplish this by adding a div around all the content after the body tag but before the footer div. Then set that div to min-height: 100%;